# How to avoid replacing space for "_x0020_"?

Tags: c#, wcf

I am using WCF and some of my methods return a class that, when converted to JSON, generate an object like this:

```
{
    "__type": "Data:#MyNamespace.Model"
    "Dado_x0020_1": "1"
    "Dado_x0020_2": "2"
    "Dado_x0020_3": "3"
}
```

I can clearly remember that it wasn't like this before, WCF wouldn't replace the space character for "_x0020_". The problem is that I have no idea what changed in my code to make this happen. I don't recall changing any configuration that would cause this. Any ideas?

This is the code of my class. It's simply a way to allow an object with variable attribute names and count:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace MyNamespace.Model
{
    [Serializable]
    public class Data : ISerializable
    {
        internal Dictionary<string, object> Attributes { get; set; }

        public Data()
        {
            Attributes = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        }

        protected Data(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
            : this()
        {
            SerializationInfoEnumerator e = info.GetEnumerator();
            while (e.MoveNext())
            {
                Attributes[e.Name] = e.Value;
            }
        }

        public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        {
            foreach (string key in Attributes.Keys)
            {
                info.AddValue(key, Attributes[key]);
            }
        }

        public void Add(string key, object value)
        {
            Attributes.Add(key, value);
        }

        public object this[string index]
        {
            set { Attributes[index] = value; }
            get
            {
                if (Attributes.ContainsKey(index))
                    return Attributes[index];
                else
                    return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have the exact same problem.  I assume from the lack of answers there is no way to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

It is WCF's [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializersettings(v=vs.110).aspx) that adds those `_x0020_` characters. You need to use a different json serializer (like json.net) if you want to use the output for something else then WCF communication.

If you however changed your `Data` class to something like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class Data
{
    public Data()
    {
        Attributes = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }

    [DataMember]
    public Dictionary<string, object> Attributes { get; set; }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public object this[string index]
    {
        set { Attributes[index] = value; }
        get
        {
            if (Attributes.ContainsKey(index))
                return Attributes[index];
            else
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

then the following WCF serialisation:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var data = new Data();
        data["Dado 1"] = 1;
        data["Dado 2"] = 2;
        data["Dado 3"] = 3;

        var dcjs = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Data));
        MemoryStream stream1 = new MemoryStream();
        dcjs.WriteObject(stream1, data);
        stream1.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        var json3 = new StreamReader(stream1).ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

will produce this result:

```
{
  "Attributes": [
    {
      "Key": "Dado 1",
      "Value": 1
    },
    {
      "Key": "Dado 2",
      "Value": 2
    },
    {
      "Key": "Dado 3",
      "Value": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

but still I don't think it would be of much use outside of the the WCF context.